# Apache spark inner join 2 dataframes getting TreeNodeException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm very new to Apache spark and I'm trying to inner join a Book table with a table which has `book_id` along with read_count. The goal is to generate a table of book names and its corresponding read count.

To start with I have a table `booksRead` which contains a record of users reading books, grouped by the `book_id` as has been ordered by their read frequency.

```scala
booksReadDF.groupBy($"book_id").agg(count("book_id").as("read_count"))
      .orderBy($"read_count".desc)
      .show()
```

```sh
+-------+----------+
|book_id|read_count|
+-------+----------+
|   8611|       565|
|     14|       436|
|  11850|       394|
|     15|       357|
|  11803|       324|
+-------+----------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

and I'm trying to inner join the table `books` which looks like this:

```sh
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+----+--------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+--------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------+----------+
|    id|          created_at|          updated_at|               title|      isbn_13|   isbn_10|           image_url|         description|           publisher|author_id|year|overall_rating|audible_link|          google_url|         query_title|category|language|number_of_reviews|waterstone_link|amazon_available|is_ebook|page_count|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+----+--------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+--------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------+----------+
|115442|2018-07-25 00:59:...|2018-07-25 00:59:...|Representation of...|9781361479278|1361479272|http://books.goog...|This dissertation...|Open Dissertation...|    62130|2017|          null|        null|http://books.goog...|representation of...|        |      en|                0|           null|            true|   false|      null|
|115450|2018-07-25 00:59:...|2018-07-25 00:59:...|Imag(in)ing the W...|9789004182981|9004182985|http://books.goog...|This study examin...|               BRILL|    73131|2010|          null|        null|http://books.goog...|imagining the war...|        |      en|                0|           null|            true|   false|      null|
|218332|2018-08-19 14:48:...|2018-08-19 14:48:...|My Life With Tibe...|9781462802357|1462802354|http://books.goog...|Your child is a m...| Xlibris Corporation|   118091|2008|          null|        null|https://play.goog...|my life with tibe...|        |      en|                0|           null|            true|   false|      null|
|186991|2018-08-11 11:08:...|2018-08-11 11:08:...|  NOT "Just Friends"|9781416586401|1416586407|http://books.goog...|One of the world’...|  Simon and Schuster|     7687|2007|          null|        null|https://play.goog...|    not just friends|        |      en|                0|           null|            true|   false|      null|
|247317|2018-09-06 08:23:...|2018-09-06 08:23:...|OCR AS and A Leve...|9781910523056|1910523054|https://images-eu...|A complete course...|   PG Online Limited|   128220|2016|          null|        null|                null|ocr as and a leve...|    null| English|             null|           null|            true|   false|      null|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+----+--------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+--------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------+----------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

where `book_id` joins with `id` on the book table with this command:

```scala
booksReadDF.groupBy($"book_id").agg(count("book_id").as("read_count"))
      .orderBy($"read_count".desc)
      .join(booksDF, booksReadDF.col("book_id") === booksDF.col("id"), "inner")
      .show()
```

but I'm getting this error:

```sh
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(book_id#4, 200)
+- *(3) Sort [read_count#67L DESC NULLS LAST], true, 0
   +- Exchange rangepartitioning(read_count#67L DESC NULLS LAST, 200)
      +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[book_id#4], functions=[count(book_id#4)], output=[book_id#4, read_count#67L])
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(book_id#4, 200)
            +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[book_id#4], functions=[partial_count(book_id#4)], output=[book_id#4, count#215L])
               +- *(1) Scan JDBCRelation(books_readbook) [numPartitions=1] [book_id#4] PushedFilters: [*IsNotNull(book_id)], ReadSchema: struct<book_id:int>

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:391)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.inputRDDs(SortExec.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec.inputRDDs(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:745)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:713)
    at DBConn$.main(DBConn.scala:36)
    at DBConn.main(DBConn.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange rangepartitioning(read_count#67L DESC NULLS LAST, 200)
+- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[book_id#4], functions=[count(book_id#4)], output=[book_id#4, read_count#67L])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(book_id#4, 200)
      +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[book_id#4], functions=[partial_count(book_id#4)], output=[book_id#4, count#215L])
         +- *(1) Scan JDBCRelation(books_readbook) [numPartitions=1] [book_id#4] PushedFilters: [*IsNotNull(book_id)], ReadSchema: struct<book_id:int>

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:391)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.inputRDDs(SortExec.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 56
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner$.sketch(Partitioner.scala:309)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner.<init>(Partitioner.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    ... 72 more
19/06/17 16:21:47 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/06/17 16:21:47 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.245.65.12:4040
19/06/17 16:21:47 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/06/17 16:21:47 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/06/17 16:21:47 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/06/17 16:21:48 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/06/17 16:21:48 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/06/17 16:21:48 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/06/17 16:21:48 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/06/17 16:21:48 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/ql/dpk0v2gs15z83pvwt_g3n7lh0000gn/T/spark-9368b8cb-0cf6-45a5-9548-a9c1975dab46
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your core exception is

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 56`

which indicates that at some point you are attempting to run bytecode that was compiled for a different version of Java than your runtime. Make sure that you are running Spark on a Java 8 JRE and make sure that any dependencies (e.g. your Postgres JDBC driver) are also built for Java 8.

Comment: You're quite right! I had JDK 12 installed and obviously my dependencies were not compatible. Cheers!